# Datagridview Rows change color

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im making an Inventory System that every 3 seconds it will check the rows in cell 5 if it is below 10. Then My problem is how can I change the color to red to those are below in 10.

```
private void belowstock()
    {
        int row;
        int qty, qtyOnHand;

        for (row = 0; row < dataGridView1.RowCount; row++)
        {
            qty = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString());

            qtyOnHand = 10;
            if (qty <= qtyOnHand)
            {

                   //red  
             }     

            else
                  //white
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is your Datagridview is binded

Comment: Is this winforms DataGridView? Do you want to change the entire row color or particular cell color?

Comment: @Co.Aden Sorry sir what do you mean by blinded?

Comment: @Junaith Yes It is sir. I want the entire row in cell 5 that is below 10.

Comment: @DontStopLearning - see the link provided by Yuriy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `LINQ`

way to Do this

```
private void belowstock()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(w => (int)w.Cells[5].Value < 10).ToList().ForEach(f => f.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(w => (int)w.Cells[5].Value > 10).ToList().ForEach(f => f.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White);
}
```

Just put this Code

Comment: Thank you for the shorter way sir! Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

try the below code in your loop:

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```